# Join takes too long

Tags: sql, database, performance, oracle, join

I have this query that takes about 5 minutes to run in Oracle:

```
select t1.A,t2.B,t2.C,t2.D,t2.E 
from TABLE1 t1 join TABLE2 t2 
on t2.X = t1.Y 
where t1.F = <integer> 
and t2.G = <integer> 
and t1.H = <integer>
```

t1 has 1.7 million rows and t2 has 31 million. I have indices on t2.X and t1.F. Tried adding indices on t1.Y, t2.G and t1.H but they didn't help. Any ideas how I can improve performance of this join?

Comment: Can you post the query plan?  How many rows does the query return?  How selective are the various conditions?

Comment: t2.G and t1.H return almost whole tables, t1.F returns just 2 rows

Comment: If there are only 2 rows in T1 for any given value of F and if there are 10's of rows in T2 for every row in T1, your object statistics would seem to be way out of whack.  A simple nested loop join using the index on T1.F and the index on T2.X should take substantially less than a second.  It would be very useful to see the query plan even if it happens to be 70 rows.

Comment: SELECT STATEMENT; TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID (t1); NESTED LOOPS; TABLE ACCESS FULL (t1); INDEX RANGE SCAN (index on t1.F)

Comment: After creating the indices in the answer below: SELECT STATEMENT; HASH JOIN; TABLE ACCESS FULL (t2); TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID (t1), INDEX RANGE SCAN (index on t1 (H, F, Y))

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the plan (including the cost & cardinality columns if possible)?  What version of Oracle are you using?  Are your object statistics up to date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at all the fields involved, a covering index on each table would involve may columns

```
t1: Y, F, H, A
t2: X, G, C, D, E
```

How selective are ANY of the criteria: t2.X, t2.G or t1.Y, t1.F, t1.H ?

If none of the individual columns are selective enough (ideally 0.5% or less), you may want to create a or several covering index that involve multiple columns, for example

```
t2 (G, X)
t1 (H, F, Y)
```

***Note:** The order of columns in an index is very important - always put the most selective (the one that divides the column data into the most distinct sets) first.*

At the expense of storage, you can make the index COVER the query by providing all the necessary columns in the index itself.  This means the query does not need to go back to table data at all.

```
create index ix_t2 on t2 (G,X) INCLUDE (C,D,E)
create index ix_t1 on t1 (H,F,Y) INCLUDE (A)
```

#### EDIT

Looks like I slipped a SQL Server DDL in there.  In Oracle, you would have to expand the index to become t2 (G,X, C,D,E) - but that increases selectivity requirements for index usage since the index key becomes very long.

Comment: brilliant, those two indices reduced time to 45 seconds

Comment: Any other indices that may improve performance? I can create them before running this query (I need to run it many times actually for different values of t1.F) and drop them when done.

Comment: thanks! any idea if there's anything equivalent to include in Oracle?